# How can I enable Perl web scripts to run on Apache?

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I have a Perl script which is scripted to `print "Hello!"` on a web browser. I am using apache as my localhost server. The OS I am using is the Red Hat 5.

The problem is that when I type the address *http://localhost/example.pl* or *http://127.0.0.1/example.pl*, it shows me exactly the entire script codes but not the "Hello!" word that should be output.

The Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "content-type: text/html \n\n";

print "Hello, Perl!";
```

Anyone has any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: Great more points for stackover flow! Hey brian did you think that I didn't follow the 'Tutorial' before I posted this question? well think again!

Comment: brian would have no idea whether or not you have read any tutorials if you did not explicitly say so. All he has to go on is the level of knowledge you demonstrate in your post.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvoted this question?  Questions are asked b/c people don't know how to do something.  This wasn't asked to increase SO pts.  It's a valid question, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it in `cgi-bin`

As you noticed, files that are not processed by the interpreter are returned as downloadable text files, therefore apache designates space where files will be interpreted/processed by the server (the common gateway interface bin).

First you have to set up apache to point to a cgi-bin directory - it does this by default, you can put your file there.
Once your file is there the URI would be something like: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/example.pl`

---

**Note:** you cannot put `html`/`js` in the cgi-bin as they will be processed and will cause a server fault.

I recommend reading more from apache's website.

Comment: I made all the necessary changes to the conf file but its still not working. Now it tells me the error of "The requested URL /cgi-bin/example.pl was not found on this server.". Do you know where can I find the .htaccess file in Linux?

Comment: Well, you don't have to put it in /cgi-bin/. You have to put it in somewhere that the webserver will recognize it as an executable file. You have to tell the webserver how to handle that.

Comment: A cgi-bin should have been created by default.  You shouldn't need to touch the .htaccess file.  Once you have it working in cgi-bin, you can use Redirect/RewriteRules to mask the path so `http://localhost/index.cgi -> http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.cgi`

Answer (score 0):

The Apache docs tell you how to configure your webserver to run CGI programs in [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html).